# Passing multiple multivalued parameters to a MVC controller from different search form

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, routes, asp.net-mvc-routing

I have a website with two search forms, both calling the same controller and action. First form is for cars, second for motorcycles. Each form has multiple search filters. These filters are multivalued.

My route file:

```
routes.MapRoute("Cars",
            "search/cars",
            new { controller = "Search", action = "Index", SearchType = "Cars", Param1 = "", Param2="" }, null);
routes.MapRoute("Motorcycles",
            "search/moto",
            new { controller = "Search", action = "Index", SearchType = "Moto", Param3 = "", Param4="" }, null);
```

So calling "mywebsite.com/search/cars?Param1=BMW&Param1=VW" should get me these values into my controller:

```
SearchType = "Cars"
Param1[] = {"BMW", "VW"}
```

Is there any way to avoid having action in Search controller declared as:

```
public ActionResult Index(string SearchType, string Param1, string Param2, string Param3, string Param4){}
```

But instead have one params[] variable which would then contain key value pairs? Parameters in both cases have different names, so I can't always use the same name. Also each search page has different number of parameters.

Comment: Your route definitions are pointless - they are identical. Why not separate actions methods in `SearchController` - say `public ActionResult Cars(string[] models)` and `public ActionResult Motocycles(string[] models)`? And your routes would be ``routes.MapRoute("Cars","search/cars",new { controller = "Search", action = "Cars" })`` and `routes.MapRoute("Cars","search/motocycles",new { controller = "Search", action = "Motocycles" })`

Comment: And have route definitions with `Param1 = "", Param2=""` etc does not make any sense (as you can see, they are being added as query string parameters because you submitting a form - your browser has no knowledge of your roue definitions)

Answer (score 0):

You may want to consider using JSON and doing a POST with a JSON object. If you're method is going to take a variety of parameters to the point where it could have 3-4+ params, then you should reconsider how the data is transferred. Perhaps create a model for the search that has the filters as fields? You could then just accept the model as an object and handle it that way.

You should also consider using two different actions on the Search controller. Even though you're "searching", you've stated that each form handles different data, which means you will probably need to handle the search differently. Maybe use a Cars action and a Moto action?

Comment: That was an option ... using POST with JSON object. The problem is that in that case, I am changing the url with history.Push, and I want to enable user to reload current (updated) url and get the same result. Or share his search form with all the filters enabled.

Comment: I see, well what about taking `string[] SearchParam` as one parameter passed in the url? Or, you could try something like this: `var url = '../search/cars?SearchType=Cars&filters='+ encodeURIComponent(JSON.stringify(data));` where you can still use a json object through the uri